# FileWatcher creation event not fired

Tags: c#

I wrote a filewatcher service for monitoring a directory recursively, and if there is .txt file contents change or new created .txt files in the directory, it will copy the file to an central folder. But I meet some problem in my program.

Whenever there is a .txt file contents change, my program works well. However, when there is a new .txt file created in the directory, the created event never fired. Below is my code, could you please help me with this problem? Thanks in advance!

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.ServiceProcess;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.IO;

namespace FileWatcher
{
    public partial class FileWatcher : ServiceBase
    {
        private string des = @"c:\b";
        private FileSystemWatcher watcher;
        public FileWatcher()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            watcher = new FileSystemWatcher();
        }

        protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
        {


            watcher.Path = @"C:\a";
            /* Watch for changes in LastAccess and LastWrite times, and
               the renaming of files or directories. */
            watcher.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.Size | NotifyFilters.LastWrite;

            // Only watch text files.
            watcher.Filter = "*.txt";

            // Add event handlers.
            watcher.Changed += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnChanged);
            watcher.Created += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnCreated);


            // Begin watching.
            watcher.IncludeSubdirectories = true;
            watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
        }
        private void OnChanged(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e) {

            string fileName = Path.GetFileName(e.Name);
            string destFile = System.IO.Path.Combine(des, fileName);
            using (System.IO.StreamWriter f = new System.IO.StreamWriter(@"C:\log.txt", true))
            {
                f.WriteLine(fileName);
            }


            using (System.IO.StreamWriter f = new System.IO.StreamWriter(@"C:\log.txt", true))
            {
                f.WriteLine(destFile);
            }

            System.IO.File.Copy(e.FullPath, destFile, true);

        }

        private void OnCreated(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e) {
            using (System.IO.StreamWriter f = new System.IO.StreamWriter(@"C:\log.txt", true))
            {
                f.WriteLine("create new");
            }

            FileAttributes attr = File.GetAttributes(e.FullPath);
            //detect whether its a directory or file
            if ((attr & FileAttributes.Directory) == FileAttributes.Directory) {
                foreach (string file in Directory.GetFiles(e.FullPath))
                {
                    var eventArgs = new FileSystemEventArgs(
                        WatcherChangeTypes.Created,
                        Path.GetDirectoryName(file),
                        Path.GetFileName(file));
                    OnCreated(sender, eventArgs);
                }


            }
            else {
                string fileName = e.Name;
                string destFile = System.IO.Path.Combine(des, fileName);
                System.IO.File.Copy(e.FullPath, destFile, true);
            }


        }


        protected override void OnStop()
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You are writing to the root of `C:\ ` unless your program is run as an administrator your log files are going to be written to `C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Local\VirtualStore\Log.txt`.

Comment: I think there is no problem for my program to write things into C:\log.txt, since when file contents changes, I saw it did write change events into the C:\log.txt

Answer (score 1):

I think, there is a problem in your NotifyFilter. You have to add NotifyFilters.FileName to get the created-event. I could reporduce it in a small solution.

Comment: What exactly of NotifyFilters.FileName will affect? I was thinking it only affect on Changed event, not Created event. Is NotifyFilters.FileName means whenever there is a filename changed, some event will fired? Then the Rename event has the same effect as it.

Comment: Maybe  the change is from null to "whatever. txt".